# Clean all GET and POST inputs easily with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, security

I have built a fairly large web application which is now nearly finished and I haven't done anything to make the user inputs safe.

Every page calls a 'midleware' object first and I'm thinking I could just clean all `$_GET` and `$_POST` variables in its constructor.

Is it possible to just use a `PHP` function to make all inputs safe or should I go though every input and clean it specifically for what it is used for? The application uses a `MySQL` database and most inputs are used with the `MySQL` database.

I'm thinking I can just strip everything out of the input apart from letters numbers and punctuation.

Comment: What do you mean by "clean" and "safety"? Escaping to prevent injections?

Comment: Yes I want to prevent injections

Comment: “Is it possible to just use a PHP function to make all inputs safe?” – No. “Or should I go though every input and clean it specifically for what it is used for?” – Yes.

Comment: "I have built a fairly large web application which is now nearly finished and I haven't done anything to make the user inputs safe." https://twitter.com/CalEvans/status/629326719988703232

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is impossible to 'escape' or make all inputs 'safe' before knowing exactly where the input is being used.

Preventing SQL injections should be done primarily through prepared statements. Both [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) and [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) extensions supports prepared statements and are usually bundled with a standard PHP distribution. You could, however, force all inputs to a specified character encoding using [`iconv`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php) and [`mbstring_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) extensions.

Validating input should be done when you know in in what context it's going to be used. If the input should be an email you are better of validating that is in fact an email once, than making assumptions beforehand. Assumptions about user input are always bad. If an input doesn't adhere to your specified restrictions you should consider it invalid/tainted.

Hope this can help, happy coding.